# Issues retreiving Prismic data by key

Tags: javascript, prismic.io

I'm trying to retrieve several data points from a Prismic document. All but one of them are giving me no issues. There is 1 data key that is returning null. I'm doing the same exact thing I'm doing for all of the others. I created a couple of dummy variables for testing:

```
/* This one pulls in the whole first item in the group with no issue */
var testGroup = /*[[${document.getGroup(document.getType() + '.group').getDocs()[0]}]]*/ null;

/* This one gets the 'time' element from the first group and works with no issues*/
var goalTime = /*[[${document.getGroup(document.getType() + '.group').getDocs()[0].getText('time')}]]*/ 2;

/* This one returns null when there is clearly a value in the document */
var testLine = /*[[${document.getGroup(document.getType() + '.group').getDocs()[0].getText('line_number__0_no_line__1_under__2_between__3_above_')]}]]*/ 2;
```

So I did a little playing around in the Chrome console, and I was able to access the variable testGroup. In there, I was able to see the value for my key that I was trying to get... so it IS in there:

[image: Chrome console showing data value]

In the console, I was successfully able to retrieve the value using:

```
testGroup['fragments']['line_number__0_no_line__1_under__2_between__3_above_']['value']
```

So, although a little hacky and not the way I wanted to do it, I then tried:

```
var testLine2 = /*[[${document.getGroup(document.getType() + '.group').getDocs()[0]['fragments']['line_number__0_no_line__1_under__2_between__3_above_']['value']}]]*/ 2;
```

But I once again got a null reference error. This isn't making any sense to me... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I had an extra bracket in

```
var testLine = /*[[${document.getGroup(document.getType() + '.group').getDocs()[0].getText('line_number__0_no_line__1_under__2_between__3_above_')]}]]*/ 2;
```

Whoops!